# How to compare community diversity of longitudinal and independent samples?

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, independence, biostatistics, diversity

We are wanting to compare the diversity of [biofouling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofouling) species on longitudinal and independent samples. The first set of samples is repeated measures data, as we measured percent cover of species on the same plates each month for 5 months (cumulative plates). The second set had new plates deployed at the beginning of each month that were removed and assessed for percent cover of species at the end of that same month (monthly plates). We repeated this setup for two summers, at 11 sites.

We have come up with a possible analysis and would like to know if it is statistically sound. We are also open to any suggestions on how to approach this issue.

The approach we are imagining would be similar to Armesto JJ, Pickett STA. 1986. Removal experiments to test mechanisms of plant succession in oldfields. Vegetatio. 66(2)85-93, except one of our collections is longitudinal.

Our first step would be to calculate the change in diversity (∆) between collection one and each subsequent collection (i.e. 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5). Both differentiation diversity (including abundances) and inventory diversity (presence/absence data) will be calculated for a better understanding of the nature of the change in diversity.

We would then compare ∆ of cumulative and monthly data for each set of collections (eg. ∆1-5 of cumulative vs ∆1-5 of monthly) using a form of ANOVA. Likely PERMANOVA.
That is the section I am not sure about. Is the change in diversity between collections (∆) on cumulative plates comparable to the ∆s of monthly plates? Because the collections from the cumulative data being compared are not independent, whereas the two collections from the monthly plate are.

Comment: Is it this [biofouling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofouling)? That is not well-known terminology on this site, I guess ...

Comment: Would you expect behavior to differ between the cumulative and monthly plates? Presumably the monthly plates offer a "blank canvas" for accumulation, so are perhaps likely to show more rapid change in diversity?

Comment: @rw2 thats definitely part of what we want to determine. We just aren't sure how to do a statistical analysis between independent and longitudinal samples in order to check.